# Visual Studio shortcut for suggestion window (arrow down)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

Is there a shortcut in Visual Studio for the suggestion widow (arrow down).

When the name of the property is not correct or class does not implement all methods from the interface, there is a arrow down under the property name or class name with suggestions (rename method, implement interface missing methods.....)

This might have already been asked but I am not sure what is the name for this feature in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about the [Smart Tag](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/16/using-smart-tags-from-the-keyboard-vstipedit0076.aspx). You expand it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.

Comment: That's the one :) Thanks.